# How to create a global item in oracle APEX

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

everyone

I'm trying to add an item in every page of my application in oracle APEX. As there are many pages in my application, for convenience, I created a Global Page, and added a region in which the item was created. Although, this can meet my requirement of adding an page item in every page, but it will lead to an unnecessary region display in every page.

I also tried to create an item plug-in in "shared components", and tried to add the plug-in in Global Page. However, when I tried to add an "plug-in" type region, apex told me that there is no plug-in installed. Why?

Is there any way to add a page item in Global Page without add an unnecessary region? If it is not possible, is there any other way that can add a page item to every page in apps without having to add it to pages mannually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are right in trying to use items on a Global Page.

Try setting the Template of the region on the Global Page which contains this item to be "No Template".

Answer (score 0):

Just an alternative way, use page 0 (Global Page) item as a variable.
To get the global item via template, like &P0_ITEM.
Or create a new item in new pages, and get the value with process - on load before header :P1_ITEM:=:P0_ITEM;